# caesercipher( unable to work if method has to cycle through alphabets)

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

for the given caesercipher method, it seems to be functioning properly as long as shifted letter is not greater than 'z'(for lowercase) and 'Z' for uppercase. Having gone over my code, it seems to me that the first two if blocks are not doing anything. What may be the issue?

```
    public static String caeserEncrypt(String originalMessage, int shift){
   String finalMessage = " ";  
   int length = originalMessage.length();
   for(int i= 0;i<length;i++){


     char shiftedletter = (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))+shift);

     if((int)shiftedletter>(int)'z'){
      shiftedletter = (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))-(26-shift));
     }
     else{
      shiftedletter= (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))+shift);
     }
     if((int)shiftedletter>(int)'Z'){
       shiftedletter= (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))-(26-shift));
     }
     else{
       shiftedletter= (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))+shift);
     }
     if((int) 'A' <= (int) (originalMessage.charAt(i))   && (int)(originalMessage.charAt(i)) <= 'Z'){
        shiftedletter= (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))+shift);
     }
     else{
      shiftedletter= originalMessage.charAt(i);
     }
     if((int) 'a' <= (int)(originalMessage.charAt(i)) && (int)(originalMessage.charAt(i)) <= 'z'){
        shiftedletter= (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))+shift);
     }
     else{
      shiftedletter= (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i));
     }

     finalMessage = finalMessage + shiftedletter;


   }
   return finalMessage;
  }
```

Comment: I have posted my answer and I think it will suit what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your conditions,some conditions are met more than one time so `shiftedletter` change more than once .
I don't know your code logic but i think you have to updated your conditions in order to make `shiftedletter` change only one time each loop

```
for(int i= 0;i<length;i++){
     char shiftedletter = (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))+shift);
     if((int)shiftedletter>(int)'z' || (int)shiftedletter>(int)'Z'){
      shiftedletter = (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))-(26-shift));
     }
     else if(((int) 'A' <= (int) (originalMessage.charAt(i))   && (int)(originalMessage.charAt(i)) <= 'Z') || ((int) 'a' <= (int)(originalMessage.charAt(i)) && (int)(originalMessage.charAt(i)) <= 'z') || (int)shiftedletter <= (int)'z' || (int)shiftedletter <= (int)'Z'){
      shiftedletter= (char)((int)(originalMessage.charAt(i))+shift);
     }
     else{
      shiftedletter= (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i));
     }
     finalMessage = finalMessage + shiftedletter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many "ifs" in your code. You need only one.

```
static String caesarEncrypt(String originalMessage, int shift){
    String finalMessage = "";
    int length = originalMessage.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        char shiftedLetter = (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i) + shift);
        if (Character.isLowerCase(originalMessage.charAt(i)) && shiftedLetter > 'z' || Character.isUpperCase(originalMessage.charAt(i)) && shiftedLetter > 'Z')
            finalMessage += (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i) - (26-shift));
        else
            finalMessage += shiftedLetter;
    }
    return finalMessage;
}
```

Comment: so what you are implying is that many if statements are being executed at once which is giving me unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the conditions into something simpler:

```
String cipher(String msg, int shift){
    String s = "";
    int len = msg.length();
    for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
        char c = (char)(msg.charAt(x) + shift);
        if (c > 'z')
            s += (char)(msg.charAt(x) - (26-shift));
        else
            s += (char)(msg.charAt(x) + shift);
    }
    return s;
}
```

> Basically this is what it does:
>
> 1. Loop through each character in the string.
> 2. Add shift to the character and if it falls off the end of the alphabet then subtract shift from the number of letters in the
>      alphabet (26)
> 3. If the shift does not make the character fall off the end of the alphabet, thenadd the shift to the character.
> 4. Append the character onto a new string.
> 5. Return the string.

You can use the method like this:

```
System.out.println(cipher("abc", 3));  //prints def
System.out.println(cipher("xyz", 3));  //prints abc
```

> **EDIT!**
>   **> I have added a more readable code that will accept upper case characters as well (the
>   previous one only applies from lowercase a to z )... :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarCipher {

    //Constants...
    public static int NUMBER_OF_LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET = 26;
    public static char LAST_LETTER_OF_THE_ALPHABET = 'z';

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String originalMessage;
        int shift; 

        //get the inputs

        System.out.print("Enter the original message: ");

        originalMessage = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the shift: ");

        shift = scan.nextInt();

        //use cipher method 

        System.out.println( cipher(originalMessage, shift) );

        scan.close();

    }

    public static String cipher(String originalMessage, int shift) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String newMessage="";

        int len = originalMessage.length();

        for(int index = 0 ; index < len ; index++){

            //get the current char, convert it to lowercase then add the shift so that we don't have too many conditions

            char currentChar = originalMessage.charAt(index);

            char lowerCasedChar = Character.toLowerCase(currentChar);

            char shiftedChar = (char)(lowerCasedChar+ shift);

            if(shiftedChar> LAST_LETTER_OF_THE_ALPHABET){

                shiftedChar = (char) (lowerCasedChar - (NUMBER_OF_LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET - shift));

            }

            //convert to upper case again if the original character was uppercase
            if(Character.isUpperCase(currentChar)){

                shiftedChar = Character.toUpperCase(shiftedChar);

            }

            //append to the new message
            newMessage+= shiftedChar;

        }

        return newMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: I thank you all for the helpful comments. This is my edited source code.(I am not allowed to use any character methods other the ones i have used)

Comment: if((int)'a'<=(int)c &&(int)c<='z'||(int)'A'<=(int)c &&(int)c<='Z'){
     
       shiftedletter = (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i)+shift);
     
      if(shiftedletter>'z' || shiftedletter>'Z'){
       shiftedletter = (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i)-(26-shift));
      }
      else{
       shiftedletter = (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i)+shift);
      }
     }
     else{
        shiftedletter = originalMessage.charAt(i);
     }
      
      finalMessage = finalMessage + shiftedletter;